# Share text-field between different templates

Tags: docusignapi

I have two different templates, each template has one document.
In each document I have dragged and dropped text field and gave it same data label of "Email".
When I type a value in one field I want it to be duplicated to another textfield which is in another template. I'm not sending the data via API, just using docusign portal.

Answer (score 0):

To see same value coming on multiple documents in the same envelope with same Data Label, then please check if below settings are enabled in your Account.

- Go To Admin
- Select `Sending Settings` from left hand side navigation
- In Section `Automatically replicate information in fields with the
  same Data Label`, select radio button `on all documents in an envelope`